# why isn't Norton transform applicable on ideal sources?

Tags: current-source, source, voltage-source, norton

1. An ideal voltage source has no resistance in series to it, so the it's transform the current source must have zero resistance in parallel to it.
2. This means that all the current passes through the short (zero resistance) and no current will pass through the load.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform will be to a current source with infinite current and therefore (so the mathematicians say) the voltage will be finite across a zero ohm parallel resistor.

Consider a 1v source with 0.001 ohms series resistance - short circuit current is 1000 amps and therefore the equivalent current source is 1000 amps in parallel with 0.001 ohms.

Keep moving the goal posts upwards and you of course get very big currents and very small resistances but it is just a theory and at this sort of level has very little practical importance to many things.

Comment: What? If \$\infty / 0\$ is some finite number, which one?

Comment: @PhilFrost was this a serious question Phil? I'm talking V = IR.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that should have been \$\infty \cdot 0\$. Regardless, can you elaborate on what the "mathematicians say"?

Comment: @PhilFrost - The answer to your question, "which one" is - any one you want. Handling infinities is done in certain branches of math, but it's nothing that can be explained in 500 characters with even a remote chance of success.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast That's why we have links.

Comment: @PhilFrost - Or Google, for those willing to do their own research on the net.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast [like this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infinity-multiplied-by-zero-not-an-easy-zero-answer)? Or [like this](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/burden-of-proof)?

Answer (score 5):

Consider two equivalent circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foIdlE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These are related by the equations:

$$ R_{th} = R_{no} \\
V_{th} = I_{no} R_{no} \\
I_{no} = V_{th} / R_{th} $$

Let's say \$V_{th} = 1\:\mathrm V\$. Then:

$$ I_{no} = 1/R_{th} $$

When \$R_{th} = 0\$, what do you get?

[image: DIVIDE BY ZERO. OH SHI-]

You can, if you want, think about the one-sided limit as \$R_{th} \searrow 0\:\Omega\$. As you approach that limit, \$I_{no}\$ approaches infinity and \$R_{no}\$ approaches zero. That gives you some insight into what happens as a voltage source becomes arbitrarily close to ideal, but you still can't divide by zero when it becomes exactly ideal.

What you are doing, by choosing to ignore the undefinedness of dividing by zero, is called a [formal calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_calculation), and while that may sound like a great idea, but it's not:

> In mathematical logic, a formal calculation is a calculation which is systematic, but without a rigorous justification.

You can also read "without a rigorous justification" as "without any engineering utility". What you end up with is a mathematically impossible circuit. Just to get you thinking, here are some more mathematically impossible circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN0l0K.png)</sup>

If you wonder why these are impossible, the answer is simply "because mathematics says so". It seems odd, because attempting to build these circuits isn't impossible, but remember that schematics are simplifications of real behavior and only the properties of the circuit that are drawn are modelled.

Answer (score 0):

Current always take less resistive path. So, all the current flow through the short circuit path. As per Norton's equivalent circuit parallel combination of any value of resistance parallel with short circuit (zero ohm resistance) results short circuit (zero ohm resistance). So, in this point of view the load act as open circuit.so whole applied voltage drop across the load (both load with current source & voltage source voltage across the load same).